# How do I round up before showing the result

Tags: excel, math, average

So I'm calculating my average grade using my school's formula. It worked but I want to Excel to round up before it shows the result.

I tried this:

```
=(3*(H3+H5+H7+H9+H11+H13+H15)/7+H17+2*H19)/6 & ROUNDUP(H21;3)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ceiling command

```
=CEILING((3*(H3+H5+H7+H9+H11+H13+H15)/7+H17+2*H19)/6,1)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Oh got it! Instead of the ceiling func (thank you btw) I used the roundup func with your sintax:

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRED((3*(H3+H5+H7+H9+H11+H13+H15)/7+H17+2*H19)/6;3)
```

or in the english vers.

```
=ROUNDUP((3*(H3+H5+H7+H9+H11+H13+H15)/7+H17+2*H19)/6;3)
```